# How to filter a collection of maps into group-by map by value?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Lets say I have a collection like:

```
(def xs 
  [{:name "Apple" :type "Fruit is a type"} 
  {:name "Tomato" :type "Vegetable are food"} 
  {:name "Pear" :type "the type can also be Fruit"} 
  {:name "Steak" :type "eat less Meat"}])
```

And I want to filter and group-by the collection into something like this:

```
{:Fruit [{:name "Apple" :type "Fruit is a type"} {:name "Pear" :type "the type can also be Fruit"}] :Vegetable [{:name "Tomato" :type "Vegetable are food"}]
```

I currently just filter the results but can't seem to figure out a good way to group-by. Here's what I have so far:

```
(defn filter-response [x query]
  (filter #(s/includes? (:type %) query) x))

(defn group-by-types [queries]
  (map #(filter-response xs %) queries))

(group-by-types ["Fruit" "Vegetable"])
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can use a [list comprehension](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) to check each item in the collection for each pattern.

```
(defn- all-occurrences [xs patterns]
  (for [x xs
        pattern patterns
        :when (clojure.string/includes? (:type x) pattern)]
    [(keyword pattern) x]))
```

Or using your `filter-response` function:

```
(defn- all-occurrences [xs patterns]
  (for [pattern patterns
        x (filter-response xs pattern)]
    [(keyword pattern) x]))
```

Then use [reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) with [update](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update) to merge the list of occurrences into a single map:

```
(defn group-by-patterns [xs patterns]
  (reduce (fn [m [pattern text]] (update m pattern conj text))
          {}
          (all-occurrences xs patterns)))
```

Calling it with the new input:

```
(def xs
  [{:name "Apple" :type "Fruit is a type"}
   {:name "Tomato" :type "Vegetable are food"}
   {:name "Pear" :type "the type can also be Fruit"}
   {:name "Steak" :type "eat less Meat"}])

(group-by-patterns xs ["Fruit" "Vegetable"])
=> {:Fruit ({:name "Pear", :type "the type can also be Fruit"} {:name "Apple", :type "Fruit is a type"}),
    :Vegetable ({:name "Tomato", :type "Vegetable are food"})}
```

**Original Answer**

First you can use [group-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by) to group by values under specified keys:

```
(def xs
   [{:name "Apple" :type "Fruit"}
    {:name "Tomato" :type "Vegetable"}
    {:name "Pear" :type "Fruit"}
    {:name "Steak" :type "Meat"}])

erdos=> (group-by :type xs)
{"Fruit" [{:name "Apple", :type "Fruit"} {:name "Pear", :type "Fruit"}], 
 "Vegetable" [{:name "Tomato", :type "Vegetable"}],
 "Meat" [{:name "Steak", :type "Meat"}]}
```

Then use [select-keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys) to filter the keys:

```
erdos=> (select-keys (group-by :type xs) ["Fruit" "Vegetable"])
{"Fruit" [{:name "Apple", :type "Fruit"} {:name "Pear", :type "Fruit"}], 
 "Vegetable" [{:name "Tomato", :type "Vegetable"}]}
```

If you need keyword keys, you need an extra mapping step:

```
erdos=> (into {}
              (for [[k v] (select-keys (group-by :type xs) ["Fruit" "Vegetable"])]
                     [(keyword k) v]))
{:Fruit [{:name "Apple", :type "Fruit"} {:name "Pear", :type "Fruit"}], 
 :Vegetable [{:name "Tomato", :type "Vegetable"}]}
```

Comment: Oooh, this is a nice response.

Comment: I realize that I left out a very important detail: the lookup for the `:type` key is based on string matching. My actual data looks like like: `{:type "Fruit is a type"}, {:type "The type can also be Fruit}` etc. That's why I have clojure.string/includes. I'll try to incorporate this into the solution.

Comment: oh, makes sense. I have updated my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: Thanks again! Great answers